# Read Files Asynchronously - Read all files asynchronously and find the maximum value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a dictionary with a lot of files, in each file the text is an integer number. 
I want to go over all files asynchronously and find the maximum number.

**What is the best way to do it ????**

This code is synchronously:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = process.argv[2];

fs.readdir(dir, function (err, filesNames) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;

    filesNames.forEach(function (fileName) {
        //a synchronous function
        var file = fs.readFileSync(dir + fileName, 'utf-8');
        var num = parseInt(file);

        max = max < num ? num : max;
    });
    console.log(max);
});
```

But I want an asynchronous function !
I have tried this, but I'm sure there are betters ways to do it.

This is my asynchronous function:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = process.argv[2];

fs.readdir(dir, function (err, filesNames) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;

    var i = 0;
    filesNames.forEach(function (fileName) {        
        //an asynchronous function
        fs.readFile(dir + fileName, 'utf-8', function (err, file) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var num = parseInt(file);
            max = max < num ? num : max;

            i++;
            if (i == filesNames.length) {
                console.log(max);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Better how? If you're looking for an elegant solution, go for promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer using Promise:

```
"use strict";
var fs  = require('fs');
var dir = process.argv[2];

// make fs.readFile to work as promise
function pReadFile(file, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        fs.readFile(file, options, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        }); 
    });
}

// make fs.readdir to work as promise
function pReaddir(dir, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dir, options, (err, files) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(files);
        });
    });
}

pReaddir(dir).then((files)=> {
    return Promise.all(files.map((file)=> pReadFile(dir + file, 'utf-8')));
}).then((arr)=> {
    console.log(Math.max.apply(null,arr.map((elm)=>parseInt(elm))));
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from widely used solution - [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package. It's doing most of the job for you.

here is some tutorial for async:

https://github.com/justinklemm/nodejs-async-tutorial

So you can use `async.each`, or `async.eachLimit` if you really have big amount of files.

Async solves almost all asynchronous cases in node.js